# Resolving types in a hierarchy of classes using std::type_index

Tags: c++11, inheritance, types

I was looking for an alternative to the `Visitor` pattern to map behaviour for types in a hierarchy of classes and maybe allow for multiple dispatch. Any time you add a new type to a hierarchy of classes, you have to update all the supporting visitors. So I came across `std::type_index`, which according to [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_index) might do the trick. I then thought, now I have to implement a `get_type_index` for every subclass, which would be related to the `accept` method of the visitor pattern. This would then only be half of the work that
has to be done for the `Visitor` pattern. But then I saw that apparently you only have to implement a (non pure) virtual function in the base class to make the whole thing work. Below is my [code](https://github.com/ToniBig/cpp-type-index) and I have the following question(s):

- Why are types mapped correctly for classes inheriting from `BaseVirtual`?
- How does the compiler do it and how expensive is it?
- Is it portable?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <typeindex>

struct Base
{
  std::type_index get_type_index( ) const
  {
    return std::type_index( typeid(*this) );
  }
};

struct BaseVirtual
{
  virtual std::type_index get_type_index( ) const
  {
    return std::type_index( typeid(*this) );
  }
};

template<typename BaseType>
struct A : public BaseType
{
};

template<typename BaseType>
struct B : public BaseType
{
};

template<typename BaseType>
struct C : public BaseType
{
};

int main( int argc,
          char **argv )
{
  std::map<std::type_index, std::string> typeToStringMap = { { std::type_index( typeid(Base) ), "Base" }, { std::type_index( typeid(A<Base> ) ), "ABase" }, { std::type_index( typeid(B<Base> ) ), "BBase" }, { std::type_index( typeid(C<Base> ) ), "CBase" }, { std::type_index( typeid(BaseVirtual) ),
      "BaseVirtual" }, { std::type_index( typeid(A<BaseVirtual> ) ), "ABaseVirtual" }, { std::type_index( typeid(B<BaseVirtual> ) ), "BBaseVirtual" }, { std::type_index( typeid(C<BaseVirtual> ) ), "CBaseVirtual" } };

  A<Base> a;
  B<Base> b;
  C<Base> c;

  A<BaseVirtual> av;
  B<BaseVirtual> bv;
  C<BaseVirtual> cv;

  auto asp = std::make_shared<A<Base>>( );
  auto bsp = std::make_shared<B<Base>>( );
  auto csp = std::make_shared<C<Base>>( );

  auto avsp = std::make_shared<A<BaseVirtual>>( );
  auto bvsp = std::make_shared<B<BaseVirtual>>( );
  auto cvsp = std::make_shared<C<BaseVirtual>>( );

  A<Base>* ap = new A<Base>;
  B<Base>* bp = new B<Base>;
  C<Base>* cp = new C<Base>;

  A<BaseVirtual>* avp = new A<BaseVirtual>;
  B<BaseVirtual>* bvp = new B<BaseVirtual>;
  C<BaseVirtual>* cvp = new C<BaseVirtual>;

  std::cout << typeToStringMap[a.get_type_index( )] << std::endl;
  std::cout << typeToStringMap[b.get_type_index( )] << std::endl;
  std::cout << typeToStringMap[c.get_type_index( )] << std::endl;
  std::cout << typeToStringMap[av.get_type_index( )] << std::endl;
  std::cout << typeToStringMap[bv.get_type_index( )] << std::endl;
  std::cout << typeToStringMap[cv.get_type_index( )] << std::endl;

  std::cout << typeToStringMap[asp->get_type_index( )] << std::endl;
  std::cout << typeToStringMap[bsp->get_type_index( )] << std::endl;
  std::cout << typeToStringMap[csp->get_type_index( )] << std::endl;
  std::cout << typeToStringMap[avsp->get_type_index( )] << std::endl;
  std::cout << typeToStringMap[bvsp->get_type_index( )] << std::endl;
  std::cout << typeToStringMap[cvsp->get_type_index( )] << std::endl;

  std::cout << typeToStringMap[ap->get_type_index( )] << std::endl;
  std::cout << typeToStringMap[bp->get_type_index( )] << std::endl;
  std::cout << typeToStringMap[cp->get_type_index( )] << std::endl;
  std::cout << typeToStringMap[avp->get_type_index( )] << std::endl;
  std::cout << typeToStringMap[bvp->get_type_index( )] << std::endl;
  std::cout << typeToStringMap[cvp->get_type_index( )] << std::endl;
}
```

**Output:**

```
Base
Base
Base
ABaseVirtual
BBaseVirtual
CBaseVirtual
Base
Base
Base
ABaseVirtual
BBaseVirtual
CBaseVirtual
Base
Base
Base
ABaseVirtual
BBaseVirtual
CBaseVirtual
```

Comment: Taking a step back, usually you **want** to be forced to update all visitors when adding a new type to the hierarchy. You need to define how various operations, represented by those visitors, act on the new type. I'm not sure I quite see how your `type_index` games are supposed to be of assistance. Do you plan to have a giant switch statement in every visitor? That doesn't exactly sound like an improvement.

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik Instead of a giant switch statement, I was thinking of map of callback functions plus a default callback for types not found in the map. I just found the visitor to be a huge maintenance burden if one wanted to add a new family of algorithms (visitor) to large hierarchy of classes. Also, these games would alow for multiple dispatch to be implemented, which cannot be done with visitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why are types mapped correctly for classes inheriting from `BaseVirtual`

Because the C++ standard says they should:

> **[expr.typeid]/2** When `typeid` is applied to a glvalue expression whose type is a polymorphic class type (10.3), the result refers to a `std::type_info` object representing the type of the most derived object (1.8) (that is, the dynamic type) to which the glvalue refers.

---

> How does the compiler do it and how expensive is it?

Irrelevant implementation details. One way is to add a pointer to `type_info`, or something substantially similar, to the vtable.

---

> Is it portable?

Yes it is. Again, the behavior you observe is mandated by the C++ standard.

Comment: While this answers most of my questions, I still don't understand why using `virtual` makes such a difference.

Comment: It makes the class a polymorphic class type. Absent any virtual member functions, the class is not polymorphic and **[expr.typeid]/2** doesn't apply.